# Removing numerous for loops from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, lambda, functional-programming, anonymous-function

I am writing some code for a web app that regularly needs to filter down an array of javascript objects to return a subset of objects.  I find that throughout my code I end up with numerous `for` loops.  I am planning to write a prototype function that can return a filtered subset using a passed in function, similar to C#'s LINQ lambda or Scala's filter but I can't help but think this has already been done, either in the core language or in an external library and I am reinventing the wheel.

Is there a preferred way to functionally return a filtered subset of Json objects without for loops littered through my code.  Syntax not being relevant, but a construct and concept similar to:

```
var filteredObj = obj.filter(function() {... filter function ...});
```

Comment: This is a really good idea.  Right now I am one of only 2 web developers on a team of C#, and I have been looking at ways to help make javascript much more like C# so they are less afraid of it.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you mean because JSON objects can be defined hierarchically, e.g. {"a": {"b": "1", "d": 2}, "b": {"c": "3", "d": "4"}}, so if your predicate function returned any object with key "b", what object should be the result of the filter? An array of all matching sub-objects? What if a sub object of a matched thing was also matched, should it be returned too?

Comment: I agree with your point, the object structure is {collection:[{object1:value, children:{children...}}, {object2:value, children:{children...}}, {object3:value, children:{children...}}]} and the filtering should be done as a filter or arrays rather than recursive down the tree of objects.  I will try and clarify my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore)?

There are a ton of functional programming tools including a `map`, `filter` and `reduce`

There's a ton of awesome utility in that library which makes JavaScript a little more, er, ahem, functional.

Comment: This seems to be the best option for what I am looking at, but jQuery grep() also seems a viable option.

Comment: the `grep()` function would also work, but coming from a Python background, there are a ton more tools in underscore that are useful (`has`, `keys`, `values`, `each`, etc) so I've got it pretty much loading by default on my site.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a [`grep()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) which can filter an array of objects.

Things get ugly when you need recursion or when you want to filter attributes of each object because then, the filter function might depend on the context.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very good idea.  You could do something like this

```
Array.prototype.Where = function(filterFn){

   var i, results = [];

   for (i = 0; i < this.length; ++i){
      if (filterFn.call(this, this[i])){
          results.push(this[i]);
      }
   }

   return results;
};
```

That would then make sure every Array in your json would have a Where method that you could use to filter (just like linq).

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting a browser audience which supports [JavaScript 1.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions) and above [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) are part of the core language and do not need library support.  Interestingly JavaScript 1.8 also introduces an [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method into the core language.